# Pivot table and FOR clause

Tags: for-loop, pivot

I have a table wqmp_gw_samp_technician_evw that looks like:
[image]

After my query I would like these results:

[image]

This is the query:

WITH
    pivot_data
    AS
     (select dbo.Initials(technician) technician, 
         fcguid,
         ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY fcguid 
                       ORDER BY technician DESC) row_num
      from wqmp_gw_samp_technician_evw)
select row_num, fcguid, 
       technician_1, 
       technician_2,
       technician_3
  from pivot_data
 pivot (min (technician) 
   for row_num 
    in (1 technician_1, 
        2 technician_2, 
        3 technician_3) 
        )
   order by fcguid;

The error message I receive is:
Lookup Error - SQL Server Database Error: Incorrect syntax near '1'.

dbo.Initials is a function that returns the initials of the technician.

I admit that I am coming from Oracle, and this query works there, but now in MS SQL I'm stumped on how to show in a pivot the technician initials for each fcguid.

Any insights are appreciated. 
Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2-CU11-GDR) (KB4535706) - 13.0.5622.0 (X64)   Dec 15 2019 08:03:11   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Standard 10.0  (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)

Sherrie